# More like this query fields order

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a more like this query agains two indexed text fields like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
            "fields": [
                "fulltext_en",
                "fulltext_de"
            ],
            "like": [
                "some text"
            ],
            "max_query_terms": 12,
            "min_term_freq": 1,
            "min_doc_freq": 1,
            "max_doc_freq": 100
        }
    }
}
```

The documents however only have indexed data for either `fulltext_en` or `fulltext_de`.

My problem now is that this query is only working if the field that is present in the data is the *first* field in the query. I.e. if indexed documents only contain `fulltext_en`, the query in the example above is giving me the expected results, but if I change the order of `fields` to `["fulltext_de", "fulltext_en"]`, I don't get any results at all.

I could not find anything in the documentation that would explain this behaviour. Does anyone know why this is happening and how this could be fixed?

I'm using elasticsearch 6.2.4.

Comment: The order of the fields plays no role at all, that doesn't really make sense. Can you provide a few steps so that we can reproduce the problem you're seeing?

Comment: I’m trying to compile a minimal example but I won’t manage to do that today. It seems to be related to the index definition as a new and very basic index didn’t had the same issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same using ES 5.6. Allowing it to default to the _all field by not specifying fields yields improved results, but it's frustrating that everything after the first field specified is ignored

Comment: @JanGassen did you ever figure out how to get your original index to work with all of the specified fields?

Comment: @JanK unfortunately not... I finally dropped and recreated all indexes and now I cannot reproduce it anymore. Looks like it just was some glitch